# Linq Group By Into with additional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have following sql result:
Table Result

[image]

Goal is to group this result by ProjectId and SequenceId. The later JSON Result should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "ProjectId": 1,
    "ProjectName": "Testprojekt 1",
    "Sequences": [
      { 
        "SequenceId": 2,
        "SequenceName": "ESN_Tauschen" 
      },
      {
        "SequenceId": 3,
        "SequenceName": "Demontage"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProjectId": 2,
    "ProjectName": "Testprojekt 2",
    "Sequences": [
      {
        "SequenceId": 3,
        "SequenceName": "Demontage"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My current linq expression gives me following result:

```
[
  {
    "ProjectId": 1,
    "Sequences": [
      2,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProjectId": 2,
    "Sequences": [
      3
    ]
  }
]

 var context = new ReworkPlace();

        var result = from p in context.Projects
                     join rs in context.ReworkStations on p.ProjectId equals rs.ProjectId
                     join l in context.ReworkStationReworkConfigurationLinkSets on rs.ReworkStationId equals
                         l.ReworkStationId
                     join rc in context.ReworkConfigurations on l.ReworkConfigurationId equals rc.ReworkConfigurationId
                     join s in context.Sequences on rc.SequenceId equals s.SequenceId
                     group s.SequenceId by p.ProjectId into g
                     select new
                     {
                         ProjectId = g.Key,
                         Sequences = g.ToList()
                     };


        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I dont know how I have to adapt my linq expression to inlcude the **not grouped properties** like ProjectName, SequenceId and SequenceName into my json result.

Would be nice if somebody could help me.

Comment: I think you can do without a `group` altogether if you use navigation properties instead of joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired result without totally rewriting the query, replace the grouping part:

```
 group s.SequenceId by p.ProjectId into g
 select new
 {
     ProjectId = g.Key,
     Sequences = g.ToList()
 };
```

with something like this:

```
group new { p, s } by p.ProjectId into g
let p = g.FirstOrDefault().p
select new
{
    ProjectId = g.Key,
    ProjectName = p.Name,
    Sequences =
        (from e in g
         group e.s by e.s.SequenceId into g2
         let s = g2.FirstOrDefault()
         select new
         {
             SequenceId = g2.Key,
             SequenceName = s.Name
         }).ToList()
};
```

The trick is to include between `group` and `by` the data that will be needed inside the grouping (in addition to the `Key` which is what you put after `by`).

To get additional fields, you either include them in the grouping key, or if they are one and the same for the defined grouping key, use the `FirstOrDefault` to get them from the first record in the grouping as in the above example.

Comment: Thank you very much Ivan you saved my day :-) it's exactly working like you mentioned!